# Activating a plugin from inside Woocomerce single product page using a check box

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i am looking for a way to activate a plugin from a woocommerce single product page, the plugin displays shipping countdown for delivery but its not relevant to all products and i would like to use a check box inside the single product to turn on and of per product page

the plugin is being activated across all products at the moment using the add action from theme mod to be able to change the position this really is not necessary so if need this could be removed and replaced with some other way on activating the plugin on a per product basis

```
$scfwc_render_location = get_theme_mod( 'scfwc_render_location');
    switch ( $scfwc_render_location ) :
        case 'scfwc_after_heading' :
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'scfwc_html_product' ), 6 );
            break;
        case 'scfwc_after_price' :
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'scfwc_html_product' ), 11 );
            break;
        case 'scfwc_after_short_desc' :
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'scfwc_html_product' ), 21 );
            break;
        case 'scfwc_after_add_cart' :
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'scfwc_html_product' ), 31 );
            break;
        case 'scfwc_after_single_product_summary' :
            add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', array( $this, 'scfwc_html_product' ), 30 );
        break;
    endswitch;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what class `$this` is referencing, or how to get an instance of it, so this is pseudo-code. But once you have the meta field displaying and saving in the admin, you can use the meta field's value to conditionally add the `scfwc_html_product()` method.

```
function kia_conditionally_add_countdown() {
    global $product;
    if( $product->get_meta( '_show_countdown', true ) ) {
        $my_class = somehow_get_instance_of_class();
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $my_class, 'scfwc_html_product' ), 11 );
    }   
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'kia_conditionally_add_countdown' );
```

This doesn't take into account the theme mod and just hard-codes the priority/position. You could add support for the theme_mod inside the conditional logic, if needed.